# ImageView not covering systemUI android

Tags: android, imageview

I am trying to have an `ImageView` of a screenshot take up the full screen (including the SystemUi nav bar at the top.  I have tried the "Immersive full screen" introduced in `Kitkat`, and that does take away the UI bar, but my image still does not extend all the way to the top (as seen by the blue bar at the top of the image).  The developer site says that it does this so that the image doesn't have to resize when the UI comes back, but it doesn't offer an alternate solution if you don't want the UI visible at all.

screenshot [image](http://i.imgur.com/uaR9gSr.png) <- I don't have enough reputation yet to post images.

Here is the code that I have tried (The commented out sections are other options that I have tried that didn't work either):

```
public class TrickScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.screenshotImage) ImageView mScreenshotImage;
    private Uri mMediaUri;
    View mTrickScreenView;
    RelativeLayout rl;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_trick_screen);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mTrickScreenView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        int uiOptions2 = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE;
        int uiOptions3 = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;


        mTrickScreenView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions | uiOptions2 | uiOptions3);

//        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
//        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        mMediaUri = intent.getData();

        mScreenshotImage.setImageURI(mMediaUri);
//        File file = new File(mMediaUri.getPath());
//        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
//        rl = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.trickRelativeLayout);
//        rl.setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Recently they have switched the XML format to include two XML docs per activity (e.g. `activity_main.xml` and `content_main.xml`).  I usually only work in the content file, but you have to also ensure that the code in `activity_main.xml` is what you need.  In my case I needed to remove one line - `android:fitsSystemWindow = "true`.  Once I removed this line, the `ImageView` extends over the status bar and navigation bar areas.